# Samba clients can't establish new connections without Internet connectivity on server

Tags: networking, internet, network-shares, samba, smb

I've encountered this strange issue where SMB clients can't establish a local connection with the SMB server if the server does not have an Internet connection.  The local connection also slows down proportionately if the Internet connection is slowed down or congested.  Internet comes back up and everything works fine.

Running on Debian 8 x64, I'm just using the default configuration aside from shares.  DNS lookup is disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found [this](https://serverfault.com/a/848638/181271) answer in another question.

I found an error in my `/etc/hosts` file pointing the server name to `127.0.1.1` (should be `127.0.0.1`, obviously)

Also enabled this line in `/etc/samba/smb.conf`:

```
interfaces = 127.0.0.0/8 eth0
```

Works without Internet now and is also much faster!